# Bulk image size/save operations

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, batch, bulk, image-manipulation

I have many image files and would like few images of different sizes to be generated and saved for each. I have recorded an action that does a few resize/save for web operations but I can't figure how to configure this to work right in automate > batch screen in photoshop cs4 they way that every next image doesn't overwrite images generated at previous save.

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Perhaps, there is other software that can do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your **Destination** is set to **Folder** and for **File Naming** you have a grid of boxes you can set options in I am guessing you typed in a name for your files in the first box and the rest are blank. This would make it repeatedly overwrite the previous what you need to do is add on an extension to the name with the next box after the **+** the default is called **extension** but you can use the drop-down menu and select something different you can use the other boxes to add more to the name.